# R : problem with the dplyr::tbl() function due to restricted permission

Tags: sql-server, dplyr, odbc, dbplyr, tbl

I work with large databases that needs to be stored into a server.

So, to work with them on Rstudio I have to open a connection to my Microsoft SQL Server with the dbConnect function :

```
conn <- dbConnect(odbc(),"myconnection",uid="***",pwd="***",schema="dbo",access="readonly")
```

and in order to use dplyr, I have to create data references with the tbl function :

```
data <- tbl(conn, "data")
```

But one of the online dataframe contains a columns that I can't read because I dont have the access, but I can read everything else.
The SQL query behind the tbl() function is :

```
SELECT * FROM data
```

and this is my problem.
Even when I try to select a specific column it doesn't work (see below), so I can't create my references and I can't work.

```
select(tbl(conn, "data"), "columnX")
```

=

```
SELECT columnX FROM data
```

I think this is the tbl() function and the call of "SELECT *" that blocks me.

Do you know what can I do ? Is there smilar functions that could resolve my problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the columns that you have access to, then one option is to bypass the default access `SELECT * FROM ...` with your own SQL query.

A remote table is defined by two components:

1. The database conneciton
2. The query to the database

When you connect with the default approach `tbl(conn, 'data')` then it defaults to a query `SELECT * FROM data`.

But here is another approach:

```r
custom_query = 'SELECT columnX FROM data'
remote_table = tbl(conn, dbplyr::sql(customer_query))
```